# Encountered the symbol "INNER" when expecting one of

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
CURSOR CUR_OP_BAL IS 
SELECT GLD.GOLDSMITH_ID, RTRIM(LTRIM(PTY.LC_PARTY_FIRST_NAME)) || ' ' || 
                         RTRIM(LTRIM(NVL(PTY.LC_PARTY_LAST_NAME,''))) AS GOLDSMITH_NAME, 
       PTY.LC_PARTY_SHORT_NAME 
  FROM PUR_GOLDSMITH_ML_T GLD 
 INNER JOIN COM_LOCAL_PARTY_MST_T PTY ON GLD.GOLDSMITH_ID = PTY.LC_PARTY_ID 
 ORDER BY GOLDSMITH_NAME;
```

in above code i am getting compile error :

```
Error(16,33): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "INNER" when expecting one of the following:
, ; for group having intersect minus order start union where    connect
```

Please give me a proper solution

Comment: Above statement doesn't seem to contain any error. Please post the whole code.

Comment: Yes, please post the code from the beginning up to that point. There is likely some error in prior lines that only being caught here.

Comment: Which tool do you use?

Comment: Which version of the database do you use? It's very unlikely but if you do have a really old version ansi join syntax might not be supported...

Comment: Yes, @Radagast81 is correct. The ANSI join syntax was introduced in Oracle 9i.

Answer (score 0):

Not Sure about the issue but what i could see in the code is using of alias name "GOLDSMITH_NAME"  in order by statement which is not possible, it can be possible only if you write one more select statement on top of it, some thing like :

select * from

(SELECT GLD.GOLDSMITH_ID, RTRIM(LTRIM(PTY.LC_PARTY_FIRST_NAME)) || ' ' ||

```
                     RTRIM(LTRIM(NVL(PTY.LC_PARTY_LAST_NAME,''))) AS GOLDSMITH_NAME, 

   PTY.LC_PARTY_SHORT_NAME
```

FROM PUR_GOLDSMITH_ML_T GLD

INNER JOIN COM_LOCAL_PARTY_MST_T PTY ON GLD.GOLDSMITH_ID = PTY.LC_PARTY_ID 
 )

ORDER BY GOLDSMITH_NAME;